# Does sufficiency implies the reference measure to be a function of the sufficient statistic in exponential family?

Tags: exponential-family, sufficient-statistics

Given the definition of exponential family
$$
f(x\mid\theta) = 
    \exp\left(
        \eta(\theta)^\top T(x)
        + h(x) - A(\theta)
    \right)
$$
for $\theta\in\Theta$ and $x\in\mathcal{X}$,
doesn't this property of sufficient statistic 
$$
T(x) = T(y), 
\forall x, y \in\mathcal{X}
\Rightarrow 
f(x\mid\theta) =  f(y\mid\theta), 
\forall \theta\in\Theta, 
\forall x, y \in\mathcal{X}
$$
imply $h(x) = g(T(x)), \forall x\in\mathcal{X}$ for some $g$?

Comment: Your quantifiers cannot be correct --- maybe clarify by replacing with words? That $T(x)=T(y), \forall x,y \in \mathcal{X}$ really says that $T$ is a constant function ...